# BuildConfig.DEBUG override to true for release build?

Tags: android, adt

Is there any way, at least temporarily, to tell ADT to leave BuildConfig.DEBUG as TRUE even for release builds?

Answer (score 1):

At that point, you should just create your own constant like

```
public class MyConfig {
    public static final boolean DEBUG = true;
}
```

BuildConfig really is meant to tell if it is a debug or production release.

Note that you can modify your own constant from outside the code. For example, on Linux or OSX:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat MyConfig.java | sed -e 's/DEBUG = true/DEBUG = false/g' > newMyConfig.java
mv newMyConfig.java myConfig.java
ant release
```

This simply rewrites the config via an outside source.

Comment: Yea, I know I can do that, but I'd like a way to make it part of the automated build process. Are you saying it's not possible?

Comment: I'll remove the answer if you really don't like it, but the purpose of BuildConfig.DEBUG it to be accurate for building. I don't know of an ant or build parameter to say create a prod release but pretend it is debug.

Comment: Yeah, the second option is a good idea. Unfortunately, I can't accept it as an answer though bc I simply wanted a definitive yes or no as to whether it's possible.

Comment: Okay, well other than asking at an android developer office hours, you could try a gradle script for a maven build in trying to override it in a similar fashion to adding variables to BuildConfig as shown here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/using-the-new-build-system#TOC-BuildConfig

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue as everytime I was running the project as android application it used to open in debugger mode but then the problem was solved.

-If you are working in eclipse you must be using Java EE perspective
-Instead just select Java perspective.

-Clean your app.
-uninstall the app from the device.
-Restart your device (Just like that so that no cache is stored)
-Run your app.

The debugger mode won't show up this time. Copy the apk generated in your bin folder and try it out on other devices as well